# How to make one of two rows in a central column determine the width of that column with Flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Does anybody know how to let the smaller, red bar determine the width of the middle column and let the pink paragraph wrap in order to shrink to the size of the red one?

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
  <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 1;"></div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"> 
    <p style="background-color: red;">
      i want this paragraph
      to set the width but i can't
      figure it out :(</p>
    <p style="background-color: pink;">i want this
      paragraph to wrap to fit the
      width of
      the paragraph above asdfdasf
    </p>
  </div>

  <div style="background-color: indigo; flex: 1;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot or diagram of the result you want (VS the current state). No way to understand your issue like this.

Comment: hit run code snippet above and click full page

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the answer, everyone:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
      <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 1;"></div>
      <div id="setter" style="">
        <p style="background-color: red;">
        i want this paragraph
        to set the width but i can't
        figure it out :(</p>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 1;"></div>
    </div>



    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 1;"></div>
      <div id="copier" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
        <p style="">i want this
          paragraph to wrap to fit the
          width of
          the paragraph above asdfdasf</p>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 1;"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var theft=document.getElementById('setter').offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById('copier').style.width=theft;
    </script>



  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```